# Android Custom section header views

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which should contain different types of data. I want to group them in sections. Requirement is that each section header should have different layout for e.g.
listview should have following structure.

```
DATA A       price     quanitity    weight    color
PICTURE       123.0       10          1       Green
PICTURE       190.0       12          2       Orange

DATA B      price       purity      weight
PICTURE      133.0       100%        10
PICTURE      142.0       92%         15

DATA C      price       quanity      weight  
PICTURE     103.0        10            12
```

How to display such data in listview. As you can see that each section might have different section headers. Does anybody knows about such listview? Currently I am using http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/ but it only allows to have fixed header view for all sections. If someone can help me modifying it or tell me anyother listview that does it then it will be real help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use different viewTypes that means that you can use different types of layout for different types of view in your listview. Simply ovverride getViewType(int pos) in your adapter. And you can set different layouts in you getView like this

```
if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_LEFT) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_bubble_left, null);
            holder.drawable = (NinePatchDrawable) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_left_layout).getBackground();
            holder.bubbleLayout = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_left_layout);

        } else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_bubble_right, null);
            holder.drawable = (NinePatchDrawable) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_right_layout).getBackground();
            holder.bubbleLayout = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_right_layout);
        }
```

But have you considered using a tablelayout?

Comment: but what about custom headers for sections?

Comment: sorry, i think i missunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

i think this link will help you. Here is a copy paste example. It just works. Is a listview with headers and multiple views in each row. 
Give it a try.
http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/